# Multiplying 2 decimal values resulting wrong number

Tags: php, mysql, decimal, multiplication

I'm sure I'm missing something here. Take a look:

On my MySQL database, the 'value' field is a decimal, like this:
[image]

My database enconding is: utf8_general_ci.

My PHP code, to show the values:

```
$sale_limit_gen = Coo::getSaleLimitById(1);
$sale_limit_ale = Coo::getSaleLimitById(2);

echo $sale_limit_gen['value'];
echo '<br>';
echo $sale_limit_ale['value'];
echo '<br>';
echo $sale_limit_ale['value'] * $sale_limit_ale['value'];
```

But what I get is this:
[image]

Whats happening? The result should be 5.00, right?? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

well multiplying 2.5 with 2.5 still results in 6.25 ;-) 
at least my calculator tells me that.

What you probably wanted to do was

```
echo $sale_limit_gen['value'] * $sale_limit_ale['value'];
```

instead of

```
echo $sale_limit_ale['value'] * $sale_limit_ale['value'];
```

so its a matter of a simple typo.

Comment: Ouch, if I at least were smart. My mistake!